# Maven - include referenced library in jar

Tags: java, maven-2, jar, osgi

I have OSGi bundle for sending mails, so it's using *com.sun.smtp* package from *mail-1.4.jar*. But OSGi service do not have access to this jar.

Can you help me, how to configure Maven POM file so *mail-1.4.jar* will be included in my bundle jar so OSGi service could use it?

**EDIT**

Error is: 
javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: Unable to locate provider for protocol: smtp

Comment: Adding the dependency to the maven pom only will not work, you will also need to provide that dependency at runtime. Did you deploy a bundle providing the necessary package(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise to not include the mail jar in your bundle. The better way is to simply install the mail.jar in the osgi runtime.

You have to make sure you have two things in place to make this work:

1. Make sure you import the required package in the manifest of your own bundle. Normally simply using the maven bundle plugin with defaults does this but you should check the resulting Manifest
2. Deploy the mail.jar into your OSGi runtime. If you are using apache karaf then simply do:
   mvn install -s mvn:javax.mail/mail/1.4.4 if not then the jar below should help. It contains a correct Manifest file for OSGi deployment http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|javax.mail|mail|1.4.4|jar

Answer (score 2):

Yeasterday, I faced to the same/similar situation. Try following:

Add the lines below to your dependency list:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
 <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
 <version>1.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Hopefully it does help

Comment: In fact it does not - I still have *javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: Unable to locate provider for protocol: smtp* exception when running OSGi service. In fact I don't have problems, when using bundle under Eclipse as java appication with *mail-1.4.jar* in *Referenced Libraries*.

Comment: Are you sure that you have access to your target mail server, if you have deployed your bundle into your webserver? Maybe you also have to configure your applicationserver.

Comment: Yes, I have tried with Eclipse application (working) and OSGi service (not working) from the same machine.

Comment: Can you provide some source code from your osgi bundle? Maybe we can get a deeper look into your bundle.

Comment: Sorry, I think I can't. I need only to package some dependencies to bundle jar using Maven, but I am very beginer in Maven.

Comment: I think you have to develop your own maven mail plugin, which you can configure it and use it in a maven pom file. Adding a library as a dependency means in common speaking language to import it. (Every body is invited to correct me). Of course you can also you use an existing plugin for mailing.

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding this code to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>

   <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
   <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
   <version>1.4</version>

</dependency>
```

Or

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

this may help you!